# Best way to do a 'Confirm' page?

Tags: html, http, forms

I was wondering about the best way to implement a "Confirm Page" upon form submission. I know that it's best for the script that a form POSTs to be implemented by handling the POST data and then *redirecting* to another page, so the user isn't directly viewing the page that was POSTed to.

My question is about the best way to implement a "Confirm before data save" page.  Do I

1. Have my form POST to a script, which marshals the data, puts in a GET, and redirects to the confirm page, which unmarshals and displays the data in another form, where the user can then either confirm (which causes another POST to a script that actually saves the data) or deny (which causes the user to be redirected back to the original form, with their input added)?
2. Have my form POST directly to the confirm page, which is displayed to the user and then, like #1, gives the user the option to confirm or deny?
3. Have my form GET the confirm page, which then does the expected behavior?

I feel like there is a common-sense answer to this question that I am just not getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must do this (I'd only do it for stuff involving monetary transactions or the like, personally), I'd recommend 2 resources/URIs, both of which follow the Post-Redirect-Get pattern: POST the initial cart checkout, create a "pending order" state (or similar), redirect to the page for that state. The user can then POST from that page to the next URI to create a "confirmed order" (or similar), which redirects to a receipt page or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

What I've done in the past is have one page that has a 'View' area with labels and then a 'Edit' area with textboxes/dropdowns/etc.  You can make them DIVs or TABLES depending on your preference.

1. User comes to page and gets the edit view so they can use the textboxes.  Save/Submit button at the bottom.
2. Clicking on Save/Submit does a postback, populates the labels with the data they entered, and allows them to view/verify what they entered.  Continue and Edit buttons at the bottom.
3. Edit is a postback and goes back to the edit view.
4. Continue does the actual save and redirection to a new page that displays the confirmation.

Optionally you could save the data on the confirmation page instead of the first page depending on your preference again.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you could do this ahead of the submit.  In the form submit (wherever that is) add an onlick that fires a modal window with a confirmation button.  My personal favorite in this situation is to use a [Jquery UI Modal Confirmation dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation).

I personally fire this via means of a Jquery .click statement in the page.

So, the document won't submit until the onclick dependency has been completed and changed to "true" which the example does automatically with the included "ok" button.

I believe that this will gracefully fallback to just not require the confirmation if Javascript is turned off, which itself is becoming more and more of an "edge" case.  In fact, some of my most staunch corporate clients are starting to accept limitations such as this case when Javascript is turned off....and they're way more picky that most any of us ever will be.

Then, you're free to submit to any page you'd like.  Personally, I've switched all of my forms over to a Jquery .ajax submit, but that's just me.  You can do it however you like.